# Given A+B+AB=0, prove that AB=BA

Tags: matrices

this was my University exam question that I got stuck at.

I tried by adding inverse A and inverse B and played around with it but can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 4):

Add the identity matrix 1 to both sides. Then you see that $1+A$ is the inverse of $1+B$, so they commute.

Comment: Sorry how does (I+A)(I+B) commute show that AB = BA?

Comment: @OngCheeWei $(1+a)(1+b)=(1+b)(1+a)$ develops to $1+a+b+ab=1+a+b+ba$ thus $ab=ba$.